# Zend Framework : Using placeholders in Helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a custom helper, I was wondering if there was a way to access the view placehilders.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper {
    public function MyHelper {
       $this->view->appendScript('myscript.js');
    }
}
```

I get: Call to a member function appendScript() on a non-object

Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone ever runs across this, you need to extend the Zend_View_Helper_Abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function MyHelper {
       $this->view->appendScript('myscript.js');
    }
}
```